# Sliding animation, not quite working perfectly

Tags: jquery, animation

http://jsfiddle.net/UhNHW/

I'm trying to get a color block to slide in behind existing content inside a small block. It's glitchy and I need to get it to work for multiple instances on the same page.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've updated it :) http://jsfiddle.net/UhNHW/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use mouse leave like this

```
   $('.container')
       .mouseover(function (){
            $('.box2').stop(true, true).animate({top:0}, 150);
       })
       .mouseleave(function (){
            $('.box2').stop(true, true).animate({top:40}, 150);
       })
       ;
```

for more instances try this

```
  $('.container').each(function() {
      var c = $(this);
      var box = c.find('.box2');

      c.          
          mouseover(function (){
            box.stop(true, true).animate({top:0}, 150);
          })
          .mouseleave(function (){
            box.stop(true, true).animate({top:40}, 150);
          });
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

`mouseout` is triggered when the cursors enters another child element of the parent div.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/UhNHW/20/

I basically add a check whether `.box2` is being animated, if so, just return without anything.

```
$(function() {
    $('.container').on('mouseenter', function() {
        var box = $(this).find('.box2');
        if(box.is(':animated')) return false;
        box.stop(true, true).animate({
            top: 0
        }, 150);
    });
    $('.container').on('mouseleave', function() {
        var box = $(this).find('.box2');
        if(box.is(':animated')) return false;
        box.stop(true, true).animate({
            top: 40
        }, 150);
    });
});​
```

Comment: Any idea how to deal with multiple instances on the same page? I know I need a (.$this) somewhere.